# Using lseek system call in C to read a structure written in a file

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

I have written a structure Student into a file and read the whole structure to the console.
Now, I want to reposition the file pointer to read information about a specific student. I want to use system calls only to write to the file (read(), write(), lseek())

Here is the code used to write the structure to the file:

```
struct Student{
char name[20];
char dob[20];
int id;
char sex[20];
};

struct Student stud[size];

 for (int i = 0;i<size;i++){
   printf("Enter name:");
   scanf("%s",stud[i].name);

   printf("Enter date of birth:");
   scanf("%s",stud[i].dob);

   printf("Enter id: ");
   scanf("%d",&stud[i].id);

   printf("Enter sex: ");
   scanf("%s",stud[i].sex);

   n =write(fd,&stud,sizeof(stud));
 }
```

Here is the code to read the whole structure written into the file:

```
struct Student studread[5];
int j=0;
while (((n =read(fd,&studread, sizeof(studread))))){
   printf("%s\n",studread[j].name);
   printf("%s\n",studread[j].dob);
   printf("%d\n",studread[j].id);
   printf("%s\n",studread[j].sex);
   j++;
}
```

Here is the code to read information about a specific student:

```
struct Student  pread;
printf("Enter a position: ");
scanf("%d",&pos);

nobytes =sizeof(struct Student) * pos-1;  
position = lseek(fd,nobytes,SEEK_SET);

while (size=read(fd,&pread,sizeof(pread))){
    printf("%s\n",pread.name);
    printf("%s\n",pread.dob);
    printf("%d\n",pread.id);
    printf("%s\n",pread.sex);
}
```

Could you help me read the information of a specific student from the file using lseek() to position the file pointer?

Comment: You might actually consider refactoring your code when you have `if` statements that end up with 5 closed brackets.

Comment: Also, you have no guarantee whatsoever that `read` will actually read all the requested bytes. That's why it returns the number of bytes that it correctly read (which you are ignoring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

Inside your writing loop you might want to write the data for one student with index *i*. Also you should use the size of the struct Student not the complete size for the data for all students.

In code it would look like this:

```
n = write(fd, &stud[i], sizeof(struct Student));
```

Here `&stud[i]` points to the data of student *i*. When using `sizeof(struct Student)` only data for one student is written.

When reading the data into memory, you must calculate the number of bytes correctly. A pair of parentheses is missing. It should look like:

```
nobytes = sizeof(struct Student) * (pos - 1);
```

If you want to just output one student you should use a *if* instead of a *while*:

```
if (read(fd, &pread, sizeof(pread)) == sizeof(pread)) {
```

This line works fine if the file description references a `normal file`.

`man 2 read` says:

> The system guarantees to read the number of bytes requested if the
>   descriptor references a normal file that has that many bytes left
>   before the end-of-file, but in no other case.

But it could already fail, if a network file system is used.

So it would be better to use something like:

```
ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
ssize_t n;
while ((n = read(fd, &pread + bytes_read,  sizeof(pread) - bytes_read)) > 0) {
    bytes_read += n;
}
```

So in case `read` returns just a partial result, it would also work correctly.

Don't forget to still check afterwards for the number of bytes read. It could look like:

```
if(bytes_read == sizeof(pread)) {
    printf("%s\n", pread.name);
    printf("%s\n", pread.dob);
    printf("%d\n", pread.id);
    printf("%s\n", pread.sex);
} else {
    printf("not enough data");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Good point. It's better to always handle partial reads even if a `normal file` is referenced. I added some more information.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. The solution posted by Stephan is marvellous and works fine. Thanks again.